# Type.GetProperties not returning any properties

Tags: c#, properties

I'm trying to loop through every property in a class, output the name of the property and the value. But my code isn't returning any properties.

class being looped through:

```
public class GameOptions
{
    public ushort Fps;
    public ushort Height;
    public ushort Width;
    public bool FreezeOnFocusLost;
    public bool ShowCursor;
    public bool StaysOnTop;
    public bool EscClose;
    public string Title;
    public bool Debug;
    public int DebugInterval = 500;
}
```

Code used to loop through them all:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in this.Options.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    debugItems.Add("Setting Name: " + property.Name);
    debugItems.Add("Setting Value: " + property.GetValue(this,null));
}
```

however when I change `public ushort Fps;` to `public ushort Fps { get; set; }` it will find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public ushort Fps;
public ushort Height;
...
```

They are not properties but fields. Try `GetFields` instead. Or, probably better, convert them to properties. E.g.

```
public ushort Fps {get; set;}
public ushort Height {get; set;}
```

Comment: How come it finds them when I add { get; set; } then? Also is there another way to loop through them all?

Comment: @user1763295 You made them properties :).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I will accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 3):

Your class contains fields only, so `GetProperties` returns empty array.

Use `GetFields()` instead

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in this.Options.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    debugItems.Add("Setting Name: " + field.Name);
    debugItems.Add("Setting Value: " + field.GetValue(this));
}
```

**or** change your fields to properties

```
public class GameOptions
{
    public ushort Fps { get; set; }
    public ushort Height { get; set; }
    public ushort Width { get; set; }
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: Note that `FieldInfo` doesn't have a `GetValue` method with two parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it will find `public ushort Fps { get; set; }` but not `public ushort Fps;` is because the latter is a field, not a property.

For fields you would have to use Type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)

[Type.GetFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`GameOptions` doesn't contain a property.They are all fields.

When you do this:

```
public ushort Fps { get; set; }
```

You are defining a [`auto-implemented`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) property which means backing field are creating by compiler behind the scenes.Anyway when you want to get Fields use:

```
this.Options.GetType().GetFields();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GameOptions
{
    public ushort Fps;
    public ushort Height;
    //...
}
```

Those are fields you have there.

---

*Either* use the [`GetFields` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx), which returns an array of [`FieldInfo` objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx):

```
Type type = this.Options.GetType();
var fields = type.GetFields(
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic);

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    debugItems.Add("Setting Name: " + field.Name);
    debugItems.Add("Setting Value: " + field.GetValue(this));
}
```

*Or* make the fields into ([auto-implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)) properties:

```
public class GameOptions
{
    public ushort Fps { get; set; }
    public ushort Height { get; set; }
    //...
}
```